# Is there any alternative of case statement?

Tags: sql-server, performance, case-statement

I have a situation where if the column value is less the 1 then I have to show `NO` as column value, else `YES`.  I am using `CASE` statement for this.  But after applying `CASE` statement query is taking to much time to execute.  Is there any alternate way of achieving this without using `CASE`statement?

Comment: Post your entire query. Looks like it's not the `CASE` statement that's causing the long execution time.

Comment: Add your code in the post.

Comment: Post your query and some sample data

Comment: but when i am removing the case statement.it is taking less time..

Comment: @gkarya42, without looking at your query, we cannot answer your question. Unless your `CASE` statement is executing another query, there's no reason it will slow down the entire query.

Comment: also add the datatype of the involved columns

Comment: I have posted the query.Please help

Comment: I'd say the problem you have is all those selects back to the same table in the different columns, including the case statement. You should probably re-factor the whole query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to say without seeing the initial code. But with a simple Yes/No it might be worth looking into two selects with a union all:

(1) First select `where value < 1`

`union all`

(2) Second select `where value >= 1`